# Is this a bug in the forecast package? Missing values cause forecast.Arima to give erroneous results

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, forecast

I am fitting ARIMA(0, 1, 1) with drift models using the forecast package in R. Some of my time series have missing values at the front. With forecast version 8.4 and prior this did not cause a problem. With version 8.5 and greater I am getting unexpected results. Is this a bug?

Below are examples. My expectation is that the missing values at the front should be ignored and the forecasts should be

```
[1] 4.644542 4.700419 4.756296
```

Here is an example with version 8.5.

```
> library(forecast)
> 
> print(packageVersion("forecast"))
[1] ‘8.5’
> y.ts <- ts(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.02, 4.06, 4.05, 4.01,
+            4.02, 4.04, 4.16, 4.12, 4.15, 4.44, 4.60))
> fit <- Arima(y.ts, c(0, 1, 1), include.drift = T)
> print(fit)
Series: y.ts 
ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift 

Coefficients:
         ma1   drift
      0.6464  0.0559
s.e.  0.5060  0.0447

sigma^2 estimated as 0.009785:  log likelihood=9.79
AIC=-13.58   AICc=-9.58   BIC=-12.67
> print((forecast(fit, 3)$mean))
Time Series:
Start = 20 
End = 22 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 4.197528 4.253405 4.309282
```

And here are the results with version 8.4:

```
> library(forecast)
> 
> print(packageVersion("forecast"))
[1] ‘8.4’
> y.ts <- ts(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.02, 4.06, 4.05, 4.01,
+            4.02, 4.04, 4.16, 4.12, 4.15, 4.44, 4.60))
> fit <- Arima(y.ts, c(0, 1, 1), include.drift = T)
> print(fit)
Series: y.ts 
ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift 

Coefficients:
         ma1   drift
      0.6464  0.0559
s.e.  0.5060  0.0447

sigma^2 estimated as 0.004892:  log likelihood=9.79
AIC=-13.58   AICc=-11.87   BIC=-10.91
> print((forecast(fit, 3)$mean))
Time Series:
Start = 20 
End = 22 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 4.644542 4.700419 4.756296
```

Given that both models have the same coefficients and residuals, I believe they should give the same forecasts. I checked what the forecast is "manually" using the coefficients and residuals. This shows that version 8.4 is giving the correct forecasts. The output of this next line is the same regardless of which version I have loaded.

```
> print(y.ts[[length(y.ts)]] + fit$coef[['drift']] + fit$residuals[[length(y.ts)]]*fit$coef[['ma1']])
[1] 4.644542
```

I have also tried using the latest version of the forecast package (8.12 as of writing this). The results match those of version 8.5.

Interestingly the difference between the two model forecasts is nearly an exact multiple of the drift coefficient, where the multiplier is equal to the number of missing values:

```
> (4.644542 - 4.197528)/.0559
[1] 7.996673
```

It seems to me that this is probably a bug because version 8.4 handled these situations gracefully, while 8.5 and greater give bad results without a warning.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/forecast/, v8.5 was released in January 2019 and superseded in April 2019. The current version is v8.12 which gives the following results.

```r
library(forecast)
packageVersion("forecast")
#> [1] '8.12'
y.ts <- ts(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.02, 4.06, 4.05, 4.01,
          4.02, 4.04, 4.16, 4.12, 4.15, 4.44, 4.60))
fit <- Arima(y.ts, c(0, 1, 1), include.drift = T)
fit
#> Series: y.ts 
#> ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          ma1   drift
#>       0.6464  0.0559
#> s.e.  0.5060  0.0447
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 0.009785:  log likelihood=9.79
#> AIC=-13.58   AICc=-9.58   BIC=-12.67
forecast(fit, 3)$mean
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 20 
#> End = 22 
#> Frequency = 1 
#> [1] 4.197528 4.253405 4.309282
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Now fixed in the dev version with [this commit](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/commit/c62772f3cdc6d4dccb728c651646ac0f4959aa47).

```r
library(forecast)
packageVersion("forecast")
#> [1] '8.12.0.9000'
y.ts <- ts(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4.02, 4.06, 4.05, 4.01,
             4.02, 4.04, 4.16, 4.12, 4.15, 4.44, 4.60))
fit <- Arima(y.ts, c(0, 1, 1), include.drift = T)
fit
#> Series: y.ts 
#> ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>          ma1   drift
#>       0.6464  0.0559
#> s.e.  0.5060  0.0447
#> 
#> sigma^2 estimated as 0.009785:  log likelihood=9.79
#> AIC=-13.58   AICc=-9.58   BIC=-12.67
forecast(fit, 3)$mean
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 20 
#> End = 22 
#> Frequency = 1 
#> [1] 4.644542 4.700419 4.756296
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Rob. So the results with 8.12 are consistent with 8.5, meaning that even the latest version of forecast is giving the wrong answer. The first forecast should be 4.644542 not  4.197528.

Comment: It looks like the issue was introduced by commit 720bb81ea2c70619f823b5576ae54ee74f0fb617

Comment: Thanks. Now fixed on github.